# Splitting data using randperm

Tags: matlab, split

I have

```
dataset=[6 7;
         5 4;
         9 8;
         1 2;
         9 8;
         4 5;
         1 2;
         3 4;
         8 7;
         6 2]
```

can I random select 90% of the data for training and the remaining (10%) for test set then repeat the split 10 times.

i.e

```
training = [6 7;
            5 4;
            9 8;
            1 2;
            9 8;
            1 2;
            3 4;
            8 7;
            6 2]  
test= [4 5]
```

I wrote this code

```
num_points = size(X,2);

split_point = round(num_points*0.7);
```

to split data but I can't obtain the result

Comment: Did you mean `num_points = size(dataset,1)`? `size(dataset,2)` is
 `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataset=[6 7;
         5 4;
         9 8;
         1 2;
         9 8;
         4 5;
         1 2;
         3 4;
         8 7;
         6 2]
```

randomly re-order the dataset using `randperm`:

```
n = size(dataset,1);
data_rand = dataset(randperm(n),:)
```

Then pull out a different 10% each time:

```
m = ceil(n/10);
group = 1;
for k = 1:m:n-m
    test{group} = data_rand(k:k+m-1,:)
    train{group} = [data_rand(1:k-1,:); data_rand(k+m:end,:)];
    group = group + 1;
end
```

But I also suggest you read up about [cross validation in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/cross-validation.html) as it has a lot of built-in functionality for this.

Comment: in each stage of splitting i want training set and test set result to apply my algorithm on it

Comment: i will apply splitting 10 times , in first time say training set=[6 7;
            5 4;
            9 8;
            1 2;
            9 8;
            1 2;
            3 4;
            8 7;
            6 2]     and test =[4 5] then i will apply my algorithm then repeat splitting with new training and test set and so on

Comment: yes - that's what this does. I used `dataset` instead of `data_rand` by accident but otherwise it works as you asked for it

Comment: @AsmaaDaoud when I run this code on your sample data, it correctly gives a `test` that holds 10 *1*-by-*2* vectors and a `train` that hold 10 *9*-by-*2* vectors.

Comment: Thank you for great effort, this code is efficient for my problem

Comment: please, Dan can you answer me

Comment: if i want 30% of data for training instead of 10% , what i do.

Comment: adjust `m` such that it is the size of 30% of `n` so maybe something like `m = ceil(n*0.3)`